# How to activate buttons using a FOR loop?

Tags: java, android, loops, android-studio, for-loop

I want to activate disabled buttons called tglBtnLevel1, tglBtnLevel2, tglBtnLevel3... from 1 till the integer received with a method.

They only way I achieve it is using switch case, but I guess there must be a way using loops. I have tried a For loop, but I cannot find the way to include the counter (i) in the line "tglBtnLevel(i).setEnabled(true)".

I would thank you any hint or help. This is the beginning of the switch case I use to make it work, but only the first buttons, there are more:

```
private void checkEnabledLevels(){
        switch (d.sendPlayerStats().getWeekTournamentLevel()){
            case 1:
                tglBtnLevel1.setEnabled(true);
                break;
            case 2:
                tglBtnLevel1.setEnabled(true);
                tglBtnLevel2.setEnabled(true);
                break;
            case 3:
                glBtnLevel1.setEnabled(true);
                tglBtnLevel2.setEnabled(true);
                tglBtnLevel3.setEnabled(true);
                break;
            case 4:
                glBtnLevel1.setEnabled(true);
                tglBtnLevel2.setEnabled(true);
                tglBtnLevel3.setEnabled(true);
                tglBtnLevel4.setEnabled(true);
                break;
```

Comment: Keep all of your buttons (ordered) in a collection (e.g. a `List`), then iterate over the list from `0...n` and disable/enable the buttons from these idizes according to your needs.

Comment: Not the solution you are asking for, but just some extra info that you can consider. Why not utilize the switch fall-throughs to write more simple code? `switch (d.sendPlayerStats().getWeekTournamentLevel()){
            case 4:
                tglBtnLevel4.setEnabled(true);
            case 3:
                tglBtnLevel3.setEnabled(true);
            case 2:
                tglBtnLevel2.setEnabled(true);
            case 1:
                tglBtnLevel1.setEnabled(true);
                break;
        }`

Comment: @maloomeister Thanks for your answer, it helps me to learn how to solve it

Comment: @YHStan Thanks for your answer. Actually I didn´t know that way, it is very useful!! Thanks for helping me to improve my knowledge!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this could be to **have all the buttons in an array** like this:

```
Button[] buttonArray = {tglBtnLevel1, tglBtnLevel2, tglBtnLevel3, tglBtnLevel4}
```

And then simply iterator over them depending upon the tournament level you get:

```
int tournamentLevel = d.sendPlayerStats().getWeekTournamentLevel()
for (int i = 0; i < tournamentLevel; i++) {
  buttonArray[i].setEnabled(true);
}
```

**A slightly different but simple way of doing this could be like:**

```
int tournamentLevel = d.sendPlayerStats().getWeekTournamentLevel()
tglBtnLevel1.setEnabled(tournamentLevel <= 1);
tglBtnLevel2.setEnabled(tournamentLevel <= 2);
tglBtnLevel3.setEnabled(tournamentLevel <= 3);
tglBtnLevel4.setEnabled(tournamentLevel <= 4);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Great answer! Very complete, well explained and very usefull. It helps me to solve the problem and to improve my knowledge. I appreciate it.